# Magento2 Site Nav loads without any css

Tags: magento2

I am trying to troubleshoot why my staging site is loading without the css I guess is whats missing see screenshot.
When I look in exception.log I see this error not sure if it is related
[image]

I did edit my default.xml file but i have undone my changes and not sure what happened.
[image]

Comment: What is your store language and country ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the css files in default_head_blocks.xml instead of default.xml